# Running openni_tracker with multiple kinects

Tags: openni, openi-tracker, openni-launch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I am using two kinects on the same computer, and I would like to run some skeleton tracking for each of the kinects.

In order to do that, multiple solutions occured to my mind :

1. run openni_tracker for each kinect : this does not work, as openni_tracker runs on the first device it finds, without letting me selecting the device I want to use (if anyone knows how to modify it, I would be glad)
2. save the data with rosbag, then replay only one kinect, while puting an invalid device id (as said here : [Tutorial Bag Recording](http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_launch/Tutorials/BagRecordingPlayback)). However, this solution does not work, and some other people had the same problem as shown in ros answers [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/33764/running-ros-openni-tracker-from-bag-files/).

I tried to go into openni code, but without success, I don't have any idea how to modify it.

My config : ROS Eletric, under Ubuntu 10.04

Any help or idea would be appreciated,

Thank you in advance,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48060/running-openni_tracker-with-multiple-kinects/) by [Stephane.M](https://answers.ros.org/users/3548/stephane.m/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1304 on 2012-11-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey everybody !

I finally managed to do it :-)

In order to have two different trackers you can create two files (named tracker_1 and tracker_2 for example), with a modified version of the openni_tracker given below. I hope it will help many people ;-)
Some lines in my code may not be usefull, and are the result of my many tests...

In the second tracker, Don't forget to change lines :

- 108 to 126 : in the second file, change all the names (head become head2, etc), otherwise if 1 personn is detected in each kinect, the frames will be jumping from one to the other
- line 138 .     ros::init(argc, argv, "tracker_1");
- line 141.  string configFilename = ros::package::getPath("multiple_kinect") + "/tracker.xml";
- line 328.  string frame_id("/kinect1_depth_frame");

Here is the code :

```
// openni_tracker_modified.cpp

#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <ros/package.h>
#include <tf/transform_broadcaster.h>
#include <kdl/frames.hpp>

#include <XnOpenNI.h>
#include <XnCodecIDs.h>
#include <XnCppWrapper.h>

using std::string;

xn::Context        g_Context;
xn::DepthGenerator g_DepthGenerator;
xn::UserGenerator  g_UserGenerator;


XnBool g_bNeedPose   = FALSE;
XnChar g_strPose[20] = "";

void XN_CALLBACK_TYPE User_NewUser(xn::UserGenerator& generator, XnUserID nId, void* pCookie) {
    ROS_INFO("New User %d", nId);

    if (g_bNeedPose)
        g_UserGenerator.GetPoseDetectionCap().StartPoseDetection(g_strPose, nId);
    else
        g_UserGenerator.GetSkeletonCap().RequestCalibration(nId, TRUE);
}

void XN_CALLBACK_TYPE User_LostUser(xn::UserGenerator& generator, XnUserID nId, void* pCookie) {
    ROS_INFO("Lost user %d", nId);
}

void XN_CALLBACK_TYPE UserCalibration_CalibrationStart(xn::SkeletonCapability& capability, XnUserID nId, void* pCookie) {
    ROS_INFO("Calibration started for user %d", nId);
}

void XN_CALLBACK_TYPE UserCalibration_CalibrationEnd(xn::SkeletonCapability& capability, XnUserID nId, XnBool bSuccess, void* pCookie) {
    if (bSuccess) {
        ROS_INFO("Calibration complete, start tracking user %d", nId);
        g_UserGenerator.GetSkeletonCap().StartTracking(nId);
    }
    else {
        ROS_INFO("Calibration failed for user %d", nId);
        if (g_bNeedPose)
            g_UserGenerator.GetPoseDetectionCap().StartPoseDetection(g_strPose, nId);
        else
            g_UserGenerator.GetSkeletonCap().RequestCalibration(nId, TRUE);
    }
}

void XN_CALLBACK_TYPE UserPose_PoseDetected(xn::PoseDetectionCapability& capability, XnChar const* strPose, XnUserID nId, void* pCookie) {
    ROS_INFO("Pose %s detected for user %d", strPose, nId);
    g_UserGenerator.GetPoseDetectionCap().StopPoseDetection(nId);
    g_UserGenerator.GetSkeletonCap().RequestCalibration(nId, TRUE);
}

void publishTransform(XnUserID const& user, XnSkeletonJoint const& joint, string const& frame_id, string const& child_frame_id) {
    static tf::TransformBroadcaster br;

    XnSkeletonJointPosition joint_position;
    g_UserGenerator.GetSkeletonCap().GetSkeletonJointPosition(user, joint, joint_position);
    double x = -joint_position.position.X / 1000.0;
    double y = joint_position.position.Y / 1000.0;
    double z = joint_position.position.Z / 1000.0;

    XnSkeletonJointOrientation joint_orientation;
    g_UserGenerator.GetSkeletonCap().GetSkeletonJointOrientation(user, joint, joint_orientation);

    XnFloat* m = joint_orientation.orientation.elements;
    KDL::Rotation rotation(m[0], m[1], m[2],
                           m[3], m[4], m[5],
                           m[6], m[7], m[8]);
    double qx, qy, qz, qw;
    rotation.GetQuaternion(qx, qy, qz, qw);

    char child_frame_no[128];
    snprintf(child_frame_no, sizeof(child_frame_no), "%s_%d", child_frame_id.c_str(), user);

    tf::Transform transform;
    transform.setOrigin(tf::Vector3(x, y, z));
    transform.setRotation(tf::Quaternion(qx, -qy, -qz, qw));

    // #4994
    tf::Transform change_frame;
    change_frame.setOrigin(tf::Vector3(0, 0, 0));//g_Device
    tf::Quaternion frame_rotation;
    frame_rotation.setEulerZYX(1.5708, 0, 1.5708);
    change_frame.setRotation(frame_rotation);

    transform = change_frame * transform;

    br.sendTransform(tf::StampedTransform(transform, ros::Time::now(), frame_id, child_frame_no));
}

void publishTransforms(const std::string& frame_id) {
    XnUserID users[15];
    XnUInt16 users_count = 15;
    g_UserGenerator.GetUsers(users, users_count);

    for (int i = 0; i < users_count; ++i) {
        XnUserID user = users[i];
        if (!g_UserGenerator.GetSkeletonCap().IsTracking(user))
            continue;


        publishTransform(user, XN_SKEL_HEAD,           frame_id, "head");
        publishTransform(user, XN_SKEL_NECK,           frame_id, "neck");
        publishTransform(user, XN_SKEL_TORSO,          frame_id, "torso");

        publishTransform(user, XN_SKEL_LEFT_SHOULDER,  frame_id, "left_shoulder");
        publishTransform(user, XN_SKEL_LEFT_ELBOW,     frame_id, "left_elbow");
        publishTransform(user, XN_SKEL_LEFT_HAND,      frame_id, "left_hand");

        publishTransform(user, XN_SKEL_RIGHT_SHOULDER, frame_id, "right_shoulder");
        publishTransform(user, XN_SKEL_RIGHT_ELBOW,    frame_id, "right_elbow");
        publishTransform(user, XN_SKEL_RIGHT_HAND,     frame_id, "right_hand");

        publishTransform(user, XN_SKEL_LEFT_HIP,       frame_id, "left_hip");
        publishTransform(user, XN_SKEL_LEFT_KNEE,      frame_id, "left_knee");
        publishTransform(user, XN_SKEL_LEFT_FOOT,      frame_id, "left_foot");

        publishTransform(user, XN_SKEL_RIGHT_HIP,      frame_id, "right_hip");
        publishTransform(user, XN_SKEL_RIGHT_KNEE,     frame_id, "right_knee");
        publishTransform(user, XN_SKEL_RIGHT_FOOT,     frame_id, "right_foot");
    }
}

#define CHECK_RC(nRetVal, what)                                     \
    if (nRetVal != XN_STATUS_OK)                                    \
    {                                                               \
        ROS_ERROR("%s failed: %s", what, xnGetStatusString(nRetVal));\
        return nRetVal;                                             \
    }

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    ros::init(argc, argv, "tracker_1");
    ros::NodeHandle nh;

    string configFilename = ros::package::getPath("multiple_kinect") + "/tracker.xml";
    XnStatus nRetVal = g_Context.InitFromXmlFile(configFilename.c_str());
    CHECK_RC(nRetVal, "InitFromXml");

    XnStatus nRetVal = XN_STATUS_OK;

    //xnLogInitFromXmlFile(csXmlFile);

    nRetVal = g_Context.Init();
    XN_IS_STATUS_OK(nRetVal);


   // SELECTION OF THE DEVICE
    xn::EnumerationErrors errors;
    xn::Device g_Device;
        // find devices
    xn::NodeInfoList list;
    xn::NodeInfoList list_depth;
        nRetVal = g_Context.EnumerateProductionTrees(XN_NODE_TYPE_DEVICE, NULL, list, &errors);
    XN_IS_STATUS_OK(nRetVal);
    
    printf("The following devices were found:\n");
        int i = 1;
        for (xn::NodeInfoList::Iterator it = list.Begin(); it != list.End(); ++it, ++i)
        {
            xn::NodeInfo deviceNodeInfo = *it;

            xn::Device deviceNode;
            deviceNodeInfo.GetInstance(deviceNode);
            XnBool bExists = deviceNode.IsValid();
            if (!bExists)
            {
                g_Context.CreateProductionTree(deviceNodeInfo, deviceNode);
                // this might fail.
            }

            if (deviceNode.IsValid() && deviceNode.IsCapabilitySupported(XN_CAPABILITY_DEVICE_IDENTIFICATION))
            {
                const XnUInt32 nStringBufferSize = 200;
                XnChar strDeviceName[nStringBufferSize];
                XnChar strSerialNumber[nStringBufferSize];

                XnUInt32 nLength = nStringBufferSize;
                deviceNode.GetIdentificationCap().GetDeviceName(strDeviceName, nLength);
                nLength = nStringBufferSize;
                deviceNode.GetIdentificationCap().GetSerialNumber(strSerialNumber, nLength);
                printf("[%d] %s (%s)\n", i, strDeviceName, strSerialNumber);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("[%d] %s\n", i, deviceNodeInfo.GetCreationInfo());
            }

            // release the device if we created it
            if (!bExists && deviceNode.IsValid())
            {
                deviceNode.Release();
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
        printf("Choose device to open (1): ");

        int chosen = 1;
        int nRetval = scanf("%d", &chosen);

        // create it
        xn::NodeInfoList::Iterator it = list.Begin();
        for (i = 1; i < chosen; ++i)
        {
            it++;
        }

        xn::NodeInfo deviceNode = *it;
        nRetVal = g_Context.CreateProductionTree(deviceNode, g_Device);
        printf("Production tree of the device created.\n");

    // SELECTION OF THE DEPTH GENERATOR
        nRetVal = g_Context.EnumerateProductionTrees(XN_NODE_TYPE_DEPTH, NULL, list_depth, &errors);
        XN_IS_STATUS_OK(nRetVal);
    
        printf("The following devices were found:\n");
            int i_depth = 1;
            for (xn::NodeInfoList::Iterator it_depth = list_depth.Begin(); it_depth != list_depth.End(); ++it_depth, ++i_depth)
            {
                xn::NodeInfo depthNodeInfo = *it_depth;

                xn::Device depthNode;
                depthNodeInfo.GetInstance(depthNode);
                XnBool bExists_depth = depthNode.IsValid();
                if (!bExists_depth)
                {
                    g_Context.CreateProductionTree(depthNodeInfo, depthNode);
                    // this might fail.
                }

                if (depthNode.IsValid() && depthNode.IsCapabilitySupported(XN_CAPABILITY_DEVICE_IDENTIFICATION))
                {
                    const XnUInt32 nStringBufferSize = 200;
                    XnChar strDeviceName[nStringBufferSize];
                    XnChar strSerialNumber[nStringBufferSize];

                    XnUInt32 nLength = nStringBufferSize;
                    depthNode.GetIdentificationCap().GetDeviceName(strDeviceName, nLength);
                    nLength = nStringBufferSize;
                    depthNode.GetIdentificationCap().GetSerialNumber(strSerialNumber, nLength);
                    printf("[%d] %s (%s)\n", i, strDeviceName, strSerialNumber);
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("[%d] %s\n", i, depthNodeInfo.GetCreationInfo());
                }

                // release the device if we created it
                if (!bExists_depth && depthNode.IsValid())
                {
                    depthNode.Release();
                }
            }
            printf("\n");
        printf("Choose device to open (1): ");

        int chosen_depth = 1;
        int nRetval_depth = scanf("%d", &chosen);

        // create it
        xn::NodeInfoList::Iterator it_depth = list_depth.Begin();
        for (i = 1; i < chosen_depth; ++i)
        {
            it_depth++;
        }

        xn::NodeInfo depthNode = *it_depth;
        nRetVal = g_Context.CreateProductionTree(depthNode, g_DepthGenerator);
        printf("Production tree of the DepthGenerator created.\n");

        nRetVal = g_Context.FindExistingNode(XN_NODE_TYPE_DEPTH, g_DepthGenerator);
        printf("Production tree of the depth generator created.\n");
        XN_IS_STATUS_OK(nRetVal);
        printf("XN_IS_STATUS_OK(nRetVal).\n");


    
    CHECK_RC(nRetVal, "Find depth generator");
     printf("CHECK_RC(nRetVal, Find depth generator);\n");

    nRetVal = g_Context.FindExistingNode(XN_NODE_TYPE_USER, g_UserGenerator);
    printf("User generator found.\n");
    if (nRetVal != XN_STATUS_OK) {
        nRetVal = g_UserGenerator.Create(g_Context);
        printf("User generator created.\n");
        CHECK_RC(nRetVal, "Find user generator");
    }

    if (!g_UserGenerator.IsCapabilitySupported(XN_CAPABILITY_SKELETON)) {
        printf("Supplied user generator doesn't support skeleton.\n");
        ROS_INFO("Supplied user generator doesn't support skeleton");
        return 1;
    }

    XnCallbackHandle hUserCallbacks;
    g_UserGenerator.RegisterUserCallbacks(User_NewUser, User_LostUser, NULL, hUserCallbacks);

    XnCallbackHandle hCalibrationCallbacks;
    g_UserGenerator.GetSkeletonCap().RegisterCalibrationCallbacks(UserCalibration_CalibrationStart, UserCalibration_CalibrationEnd, NULL, hCalibrationCallbacks);

    if (g_UserGenerator.GetSkeletonCap().NeedPoseForCalibration()) {
        g_bNeedPose = TRUE;
        if (!g_UserGenerator.IsCapabilitySupported(XN_CAPABILITY_POSE_DETECTION)) {
            ROS_INFO("Pose required, but not supported");
            return 1;
        }

        XnCallbackHandle hPoseCallbacks;
        g_UserGenerator.GetPoseDetectionCap().RegisterToPoseCallbacks(UserPose_PoseDetected, NULL, NULL, hPoseCallbacks);

        g_UserGenerator.GetSkeletonCap().GetCalibrationPose(g_strPose);
    }

    g_UserGenerator.GetSkeletonCap().SetSkeletonProfile(XN_SKEL_PROFILE_ALL);

    nRetVal = g_Context.StartGeneratingAll();
    CHECK_RC(nRetVal, "StartGenerating");

    ros::Rate r(30);

        
        ros::NodeHandle pnh("~");
        string frame_id("/kinect1_depth_frame");
        pnh.getParam("camera_frame_id", frame_id);
                
    while (ros::ok()) {
        g_Context.WaitAndUpdateAll();
        publishTransforms(frame_id);
        r.sleep();
    }

    g_Context.Shutdown();
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT : Answer to the comment. In the last version I modified, here are the lines :

```
int chosen=0;
if (argc != 2)
{
    printf("Choose device to open (1): ");
    int nRetval = scanf("%d", &chosen);
}
else
{
chosen = atoi(argv[1]);
}

    // create it
    xn::NodeInfoList::Iterator it = list.Begin();
    for (i = 1; i < chosen; ++i)
    {
        it++;
    }
```

and

```
int chosen_depth = 1;
/*if (argc != 2)
{
    printf("Choose device to open (1): ");
    int nRetval_depth = scanf("%d", &chosen_depth);
}
else
{
chosen_depth = atoi(argv[1]);
}*/
    

    // create it
    xn::NodeInfoList::Iterator it_depth = list_depth.Begin();
    for (i = 1; i < chosen_depth; ++i)
    {
        it_depth++;
    }
```

Indeed, it seems that the second choice doesn't change anything. So you have to let it to 1.
The modification of the first choice code permits to pass the kinect we want to chose as an argument of the node, as following in a launch file :

```
<!-- Launching first tracker-->
<node pkg="multiple_kinect" type="tracker_skeleton_1" name="tracker_1" args="1"/>

<!-- Launching second tracker-->
<node pkg="multiple_kinect" type="tracker_skeleton_2" name="tracker_2" args="2"/>
```

NEW EDIT : answer to one comment, content of the tracker.xml file :

```
<OpenNI>
    <Licenses>
    </Licenses>
    <Log writeToConsole="false" writeToFile="false">
        <!-- 0 - Verbose, 1 - Info, 2 - Warning, 3 - Error (default) -->
        <LogLevel value="3"/>
        <Masks>
            <Mask name="ALL" on="true"/>
        </Masks>
        <Dumps>
        </Dumps>
    </Log>
    <ProductionNodes>
        <Node type="Depth" name="Depth1">
            <Configuration>
                <MapOutputMode xRes="640" yRes="480" FPS="30"/>
                <Mirror on="false"/>
            </Configuration>
        </Node>
    </ProductionNodes>
</OpenNI>
```

---

Originally posted by [Stephane.M](https://answers.ros.org/users/3548/stephane.m/) with karma: 1304 on 2012-11-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Stephane.M](https://answers.ros.org/users/3548/stephane.m/) on 2013-02-07**:
This answer works also on ROS Groovy and Ubuntu 12.10 :-)

**Comment by [da-na](https://answers.ros.org/users/4159/da-na/) on 2013-04-22**:
Hi there!

I'm using your code Stephane.M, but unfortunately, when I try it out, it doesn't work in 100%, namely:  at the begining I had problem with core dump (now it doesn't happen), but now I noticed, that it doesn't matter if I chose device 1 or 2, it always connects to the same Kinect.

**Comment by [Stephane.M](https://answers.ros.org/users/3548/stephane.m/) on 2013-04-22**:
Hi, sorry for late response. If you want to connect to kinect 1, put both variables to 1. If you want to connect to kinect 2, put first 2 then 1. It should work then. (Personnally, I put it in my launch file). See my edit in my answer.

**Comment by [da-na](https://answers.ros.org/users/4159/da-na/) on 2013-04-23**:
Thank you Stephane!! :)

**Comment by [CryptoKnight](https://answers.ros.org/users/19952/cryptoknight/) on 2014-08-07**:
Hi there!
where can i find the multiple_kinect/tracker.xml file ?
pls tell so i would be able to use your code...

Thanks :-)

**Comment by [Stephane.M](https://answers.ros.org/users/3548/stephane.m/) on 2014-08-07**:
This is an openni File... I edit my answer to show you the content, but you should have found it by yourself :-S
Good luck anyway ^^

**Comment by [dinosaur](https://answers.ros.org/users/21732/dinosaur/) on 2015-08-18**:
Stephane, thanks for all your work! I'm having trouble duplicating all you changes. Do you have the working code available in a repository that I could clone?